# define variable in linux that can be access in php

Tags: php, linux, variables, environment

I add a variable in whole linux varibale in `/etc/profile`

```
export MYNAME="My Value"
```

how can i access this value in php source code during run via apache web server?
in $_SERVER this value doesn't exist.

just this keys appear on $_ENV:

```
_ENV["APACHE_RUN_DIR"]  /var/run/apache2
_ENV["APACHE_PID_FILE"] /var/run/apache2.pid
_ENV["PATH"]            /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
_ENV["APACHE_LOCK_DIR"] /var/lock/apache2
_ENV["LANG"]            C
_ENV["APACHE_RUN_USER"] www-data
_ENV["APACHE_RUN_GROUP"]    www-data
_ENV["APACHE_LOG_DIR"]  /var/log/apache2
_ENV["PWD"]                 /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to set an environment variable for a daemon process is trickier than it sounds. Only interactive login bash shells source `/etc/profile`, which probably doesn't match the criteria of your web server process. See [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) for more information.

However, you can [set environment variables in Apache and PHP](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch08_22.htm).

In Apache configuration file:

```
SetEnv ENV_VAR var_value
```

Restart, the server. Then you should be able to fetch this variable using `$_ENV` in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the variables are exported under the correct user, `$_ENV` should contain them.

See: http://se.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php

Comment: just special keys appear on $_ENV. not my value

Comment: @sweb you may want to refer to Geoff's answer